# The meaning of "but he had nails, that one, and the other protested. . . ."

Tags: meaning

> ‘But it was my umbrella which at that moment began to take the stage.
>   It receded from me with those two young attached to different points
>   of its circumference. At the same time it gyrated painfully in that
>   shadow there. I followed, stupefied, and demanded some explanation of
>   the outrage. It replied in two voices of an equal regret that it was
>   attached and could not free itself. I hastened to aid. They said
>   afterwards they misconstrued my motives. All I know is that my
>   umbrella, open always, but tortured by unequal compressions, descended
>   indescribably those three steps here into the body of the church,
>   where the congregation awaited my discourse. On one side of its large
>   circle, which you see, was an acolyte, facing inwards, clawing at the
>   laces on his bosom and his elbow. On another was his companion,
>   inextricably caught high up under the armpit, which he could not reach
>   with the other hand, because he was facing outwards, pinned there by
>   his vestments. The central effect, Monsieur, was that of an undevout
>   pagoda conducting a pas de trois in a sacred edifice, to the
>   accompaniment of increasing whimpers. This was before they collapsed,
>   those young. Whether by accident or design, the child facing inwards
>   snatched at the back of the head of the other. We shave our boys'
>   heads in France, fortunately; **but he had nails, that one, and the
>   other protested. . . .**

This is from ["The Miracle of Saint Jubanus"](https://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/LimitsRenewals/saintjubanus.html) by Rudyard Kipling.

I can't understand the meaning of the sentence below.
**but he had nails, that one, and the other protested. . . .**

I am glad if somebody would kindly teach me.

Comment: It appears to be a reference to **finger nails** (that scratched the head of the protesting boy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment!